# How do I remove the blank line between citations using the achemso package?

Tags: bibtex, citing, achemso

I'm using the achemso package (but *not* the achemso class) to format my citations, but would like to remove the blank line between citations. Here is a MWE demonstrating my current output:

```
documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[etalmode=truncate, maxauthors=2]{achemso}                            

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Leznoff,
author ="Hayes, Cassandra E. and Leznoff, Daniel B.",
title  ="Paramagnetic metal complexes of diamido donor ligands",
journal  ="Dalton Trans.",
year  ="2012",
volume  ="41",
pages  ="5743",
}
@article{poly,
author = {Schrock, Richard R. and Baumann, Robert and Reid, Steven M. and Goodman, Jonathan T. and Stumpf, Rüdiger and Davis, William M.},
title = {Synthesis of Titanium, Zirconium, and Hafnium Complexes that Contain Diamido Donor Ligands of the Type [(t-BuN-o-C6H4)2O]2- and an Evaluation of Activated Versions for the Polymerization of 1-Hexene},
journal = {Organometallics},
volume = {18},
pages = {3649},
year = {1999},
}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Here is a really awesome grant proposal.\cite{Leznoff}. 
Sadly it wastes space with blank lines between each citation.\cite{poly}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

I'd like to do something like

```
documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[etalmode=truncate, maxauthors=2]{achemso}                            

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Leznoff,
author ="Hayes, Cassandra E. and Leznoff, Daniel B.",
title  ="Paramagnetic metal complexes of diamido donor ligands",
journal  ="Dalton Trans.",
year  ="2012",
volume  ="41",
pages  ="5743",
}
@article{poly,
author = {Schrock, Richard R. and Baumann, Robert and Reid, Steven M. and Goodman, Jonathan T. and Stumpf, Rüdiger and Davis, William M.},
title = {Synthesis of Titanium, Zirconium, and Hafnium Complexes that Contain Diamido Donor Ligands of the Type [(t-BuN-o-C6H4)2O]2- and an Evaluation of Activated Versions for the Polymerization of 1-Hexene},
journal = {Organometallics},
volume = {18},
pages = {3649},
year = {1999},
}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Here is a really awesome grant proposal.\cite{Leznoff}. 
Sadly it wastes space with blank lines between each citation.\cite{poly}

{\singlespacing
\bibliography{\jobname}
}
\end{document}
```

But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The separation you see is the `\itemsep`, that the `achemso` package sets in the bibliography equal to `\bibsep`. So the answer is to declare

```
\setlength{\bibsep}{0pt}
```

in your preamble. Use a different value if you want some spacing. The default is `8.0pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt` (it's a rubber length).